# Listening socket.io events and updating LiveData (a class of android.arch.lifecycle)in application class android

Tags: java, android, socket.io, android-room, android-livedata

I am working on a chat application and Currently I am listening and emitting socket events in an Activity.

Now i want to listen all the socket events even when chat activity is not in foreground as i want to store all the messages from different users in the local DB at the same time i want to update LiveData to update UI.

In order to achieve this I am listening socket events in the Application class as following:

```
public class ChatApplication extends Application {

public Socket mSocket;
private Map<String, Boolean> receivedFriendEventsMap = new HashMap<>();
private List<Result> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();
private AppDatabase database;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        //mSocket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Instance = this;
    applicationHandler = new Handler(getInstance().getMainLooper());
    NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(ChatApplication.getInstance());
    //mSocket.connect();
    database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());

    mSocket.on("friend_status", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d(TAG, "" + args[0] + args[1]);
            receivedFriendEventsMap.put((String) args[0], (Boolean) args[1]);
        }
    });

    mSocket.on("listen_friend_message", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d(TAG, "listen_friend_message: " + (String) args[0] + args[1]);

            SocketMessage socketMessage = new Gson().fromJson((String) args[0], SocketMessage.class);
            //database.socketMessageDao().addMessage(socketMessage);
            mSocket.emit("trigger_friend_message_delivered", socketMessage.getMsg_id(), socketMessage.getSender_id(), socketMessage.getReceiver_id(), args[1]);
        }
    });

    SocketMessage socketMessage = new Gson().fromJson((String) result, SocketMessage.class);
    //database.socketMessageDao().addMessage(socketMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, new Gson().toJson(database.socketMessageDao().getAllMessages(), new TypeToken<List<SocketMessage>>() {
    }.getType()));
}
```

Is this the right approach? If not, could anyone please suggest me some good solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your code works, then this question should be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sure @JamesZ as of now i want to know the pros and cons of this approach

Comment: Do you need the sockets listening when the application is in the background, or only when the application is open, but available in each activity? If you post this to code review let me know, I have recently done something similar.

Comment: @JamesPooley I want sockets listening when the application is running(either in background or in foreground but not when it is closed). And i want this should be available in each activity. Please let me know if i am not clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **LifeCycleService** to connect and listen to sockets and then use service binding to observe changes in activity

This is a service class that connects to the socket and has MutableLiveData() **socketData** that observe the connection of the socket (You can create any type of LiveDataObject and observe inactivity)

```
 class SocketService : LifecycleService() {
    val socketData  = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var mSocket: Socket? = null
    private val mBinder = SocketBinder()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mSocket?.let {
            if (!it.connected()) it.connect()
        } ?: run {
            initSocketConnection()
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        mSocket?.let {
            if (!it.connected()) it.connect()
        } ?: run {
            initSocketConnection()
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        super.onBind(intent)
        return mBinder
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onRebind(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onRebind(intent)
    }

    private fun initSocketConnection() {
        try {
            val options = IO.Options()
            options.timeout = 5000
            options.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
            mSocket = IO.socket(BuildConfig.SOCKET_SERVER_ADDRESS, options)
            connectSocket()
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    private fun connectSocket() {
        mSocket?.let {
            it.connect()
            it.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
                connectSocketListener()
                Log.e(SOCKET_TAG, "Connection Successful")
                socketData.postValue(  "Connection Successful for live data")
            }
            it.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) { args ->
                Log.e(SOCKET_TAG, "Connection Fail " + args[0].toString())
            }
            it.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) { args ->
                Log.e(SOCKET_TAG, "Connection Fail " + args[0].toString())
            }
            it.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR) { args ->
                Log.e(SOCKET_TAG, "Connection Fail " + args[0].toString())
            }
            it.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING) {}

        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopSocket()
    }

    private fun stopSocket() {
        mSocket?.let {
            it.disconnect()
            it.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {}
            it.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {}
            it.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {}
            it.off(Socket.EVENT_ERROR) {}
            it.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING) {}
            disconnectSocketListener()
        }
    }

    private fun connectSocketListener() {

    }

    private fun disconnectSocketListener() {

    }

    inner class SocketBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): SocketService = this@SocketService
    }
}
```

Now in Activity you need to bind this service and listen to changes in LiveData object

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mService: SocketService? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private val mConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            mService = (service as SocketService.SocketBinder).getService()
            mService?.let {
                it.socketData.observe(it) { arg ->
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TAG, arg)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {

        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart() 
        val intent = Intent(this, SocketService::class.java)
        bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
       
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        try {
            mService?.let {
                unbindService(mConnection)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

You can see when socket is connected i am posting value in LiveData and when it is bounded I am registering an observer to listen data.

Comment: You are the real MVP, thanks a lot for your help !!